# Cakephp 3.x and Translations

Tags: cakephp, routes, internationalization

I am trying to translate my page. So far so good I am using functions in my controller where I set `I18n::locale('en_US');` etc.

This worked great for 10 subpages and nothing really to add or edit. But now I have a login, users and more. So simple writing all these routes like:

```
Router::scope('/en', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'english', 'home']);
```

seems a little stupid. I tried using Admads I18N, but I don´t get the docs. Does it actually do the job I did by hand before? Well anyways, is there an automated way to do this? I mean setting the locale once and then the plugin just adds the en/de/it to the URL.

I know this is not exactly an coding question - it kind of is if you point it at Admads I18N Plugin.

Comment: Read http://florian-kraemer.net/2015/07/cakephp-3-0-i18n-language-inside-the-url/

Comment: Well this just gives a language parameter and that looks like crap. ?language=en etc....

Also I don´t understand why no one is giving specific examples, the ones in     `Router::scope('/:language/*', function ($routes) {
 // All URLs with the language go here
});` don´t have any too.

Comment: Layer 8 problem. *You* do something wrong, guess rewrite rules are not correct configured for the webserver. The article works just fine. We have 18 languages and I wrote the article for a site that actually uses this code without the language as query param "looking like crap"... The comment inside the code snippet is pretty clear. What's the challenge in understanding "*All URLs with the language go here*"?

Comment: Well can you give an exmaple or two?